# subtracting two columns from pandas dataframe and store the result in third column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, subtraction

I have a DataFrame, `df`, with 3 columns and I want to perform subtraction as follows:

```
df['available'] = df['recommended'] - df['manual input']
```

But I am getting an error stating:

> unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'int' and 'str'

I have also tried doing

```
df['available'] = df['recommended'].sub(df['manual input'])
```

but it shows the same error.

Also I would like to know that does it returns Series if we try to get particular column from dataframe??

Comment: What do you expect to happen when you subtract a string from an int or vice versa? Unlike JS, they aren't coerced.

Comment: `df['available'] = df['recommended'] - df['manual input'].astype(int)` ?

Comment: It is, what the error message says. Inputs are strings, you have to convert them with `int()` or `float()`, before adding them to your dataframe. Alternatively, you can convert the data type of a column. [See for instance here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15891038/change-data-type-of-columns-in-pandas). But all of this are just guesses, since you didn't provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @COLDSPEED This helped out. Thankyou!

Comment: Thankyou @Piinthesky

Comment: jezrael provided a good example, if you want to perform the addition, but keep the string column.

Comment: @jezrael it worked completely fine for me. Thanks alot

Comment: @Rishikesh - you are welcome!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to convert values to numeric - e.g. to `integer`s:

```
df['available'] = df['recommended'] - df['manual input'].astype(int)
```

Or to `float`s:

```
df['available'] = df['recommended'] - df['manual input'].astype(float)
```

Answer (score -2):

df['available'] = df['recommended'].values - df['manual input'].values

Comment: This would produce the same error message, the OP gets in the first place.

Comment: now only tried with same its working here