# add columns by conditional

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, calculated-columns

I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"A1": [22,25,27,35],
        "A2": [23,54,71,52],
        "A3": [21,27,26,31],
        "A1_L1": [21,27,26,31],
        "A1_L2": [21,27,26,31],
        "A2_L1": [21,27,26,31],
        "A3_L1": [21,27,26,31],
        "A3_L2": [21,27,26,31],
        "A3_L3": [21,27,26,31]
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ["A1", "A2","A3","A1_L1","A1_L2","A2_L1","A3_L1","A3_L2","A3_L3"])
```

I want to add automaticaly a new column for each column with an L in it. The information in this column will be the subtraction column A - A_L

For example,

```
A1_L1_new=A1-A1_L1 
A1_L2_new=A1-A1_L2  
A2_L1_new=A2-A2_L1
A3_L1_new=A3-A3_L1
A3_L2_new=A3-A3_L2
A3_L3_new=A3-A3_L3
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work for you?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [subtracting two columns from pandas dataframe and store the result in third column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48339263/subtracting-two-columns-from-pandas-dataframe-and-store-the-result-in-third-colu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, import library regex:

```py
import re
```

Then, take columns' names as list.

```py
col_names = df.columns.tolist()
```

1. For each column name, check if there is *L* in it.
2. If it exists, separate with regex the *A* and the *L*.
3. Then create the string based on these *A*s and *L*s.
4. Finally, create the column with the string name we just created, and subtract the columns of the corresponding *A* and *L*.

```py
for i in col_names:
    if 'L' in i: #checks if name contains 'L'
        x = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'[A,L][1-9]', i)] # place in list, the 'A' and 'L'    
        foo = str(x[0]) + "-" + str(x[1]) + '_new' # Create new name, based on 'A' and 'L'
        df[foo] = df[x[0]] - df[i] # Subtract the corresponding columns.

df
```

In case you wonder what regex does:

- [A,L] finds a match that starts with *A* or *L*,
- [1-9] matches any digit. (you can also write instead **\d**, that matches any digit)